# iphone full display of image in other view

Tags: iphone

I have view with imageview with small size and image is set to imageview in MainClass. I am providing a option to view full image.

What i need is whenever fullview option is clicked an other view named NextClass should navigate with the image of MainClass

How should i do?

Answer (score 0):

When u push to other view controller pass the name of the image to that class.Have a UIImageView there with a full screen size. In the loadView method of tat class just set the image property of the imageView to passed image name like this,

```
fullImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:passedImgNameString];
```

To pass the name u can have a method declared in that class with a string parameter and call it from the rootview class or else u can use NSUserDefaults or else u can also declare a NSString as  a property in that full screen view class and set its value from root class.

Hope this helps...

Comment: i cannot pass the imageview.image to NextClass

Comment: i am asking u to pass the name of the image ...tat is the string not the entire image.. hope i have made myself clear now...

Comment: :i got it, but image is blur. how can i implement full display of image as in Photo Library?

Comment: @duk are u using navigation controller based application

Comment: @duk hide the navigation bar by setting its hidden property true....and "Status bar is initially hidden " property to YES in project plist file....u will get full screen